# Application built successfully from Xcode, created .ipa file is installed however not launching

Tags: iphone, xcode10.1

I am able to build & install (.ipa) my Kony app from xCode 10.1, however whenever i am trying to launch it, it is crashing without any logs.

I have done below things:
1. Reinstall of Xcode 10.1
2. Delete all certificates & profile & reinstall it again
3. Edit scheme->Run->Options->Launch due to background fetch event (Check - uncheck)
4. Multiple times i cleaned build folder.

Expected result - App .ipa should launched when it is build with Xcode10.

Actual result - App .ipa file is crashing when launching

Answer (score 0):

Try following options:

1. Try to clear viz data
2. While extracting kar file, notice any error/exception showing in terminal.
3. Set Java Path -> by using following command:
   export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/KonyVisualizerEnterprise8.4.5.0/jdk.jdk/Contents/Home
   //Give your visualizer path in Mac.
4. Try to run on simulator.
5. Check splash screen and app icons are there or not.
6. Check XCode debug logs.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when the cert, or the distribution profile used to package the app has expired.

But at least the app can be deployed and run on the device or the simulator using Xcode, without packaging the build.

Cordially,
Hervé N.